# 3rd party jQuery JS and custom JS together

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, 3rd-party-library

I read many many stackechange threads and internet pages, and still do not get how to do such a simple task as using Javascript. I try my luck...

- I use 3rd party jQuery Plugins (*bxslider*, *modaal*)
- I have a `app.js` , that have to be loaded on each pages.

The result of what i have done, is that sometimes it works correctly, sometimes i have javascript errors "*Jquery not defined*" in modaal or bx, and following it, bx and modaal not defined in my app.

My `require-config.js` :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "modaal": "js/vendor/modaal/dist/js/modaal",
            "bxslider": "js/vendor/bxslider-4/dist/jquery.bxslider",
            "app": "js/app",
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'modaal': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bxslider': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$.fn.bxSlider'
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'bxslider', 'modaal']
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "app"
    ]
};
```

- My `app.js` is surrounded by:

`require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','bxslider','modaal'], function($){
...
});`

**What do i miss ?**

The very cool thing is that it works 70% of the time. It's probably a loading time pb, so dependencies are not ok...

It's getting me crazy to pass so much time on a so much simple task.

edit: i tried many things about the "exports" param of bxslider...

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to not modify my 3rd party librairies, because i find it simply ridiculous.

I had to surround theirs codes by

`require(['jquery'], function($){
...
});`

If someone has a cleaner functionnal option 100% of the time, i'm all hear...